# UIImagePickerController didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo not being called

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm having trouble with using a UIImagePickerController. Basically, though the picker is being displayed fine, the UIImagePickerController didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method is refusing to be called (I've tried NSLogging all the way through, it just doesn't get called). Here's my code (I've defined imgPicker in the header as an UIImagePickerController):

```
-(IBAction)grabImage {
    self.imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.imgPicker.allowsImageEditing = YES;
    self.imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentModalViewController:self.imgPicker animated:YES];
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    imgview.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Anyone have any idea as to why it isn't being called?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you set the delegate property of `UIImagePickerController` , if not do as below

```
myImagePickerController.delegate = self;
```

also confirm with the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` protocol,

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Though I'm getting this error (which doesn't seem to affect anything): class 'myClass' does not implement the 'UINavigationControllerDelegate' protocol. I'm assuming that has something to do with not having implemented the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate protocol, but I have no idea how to do that.

PS: Forgive my newbieness. :p

Comment: It did, but I'm still waiting for an answer to the above comment...\

Comment: <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>

Comment: When this delegate will be called? Will it be called as soon as you shot the pic or once you select use photo in the preview screen?