# UIImagePickerController didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo not being called when cameraOverlyView property is assigned

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I set up a `UIImagePickerController` modal view to record a video, and once the user chooses "Use Video" it dismisses the view controller fine and does exactly what I'd like. However, as soon as I add a cameraOverlayView, which is just a UIView with nothing special going on, `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` is never called. Even if I put an NSLog on the first line of that function, I don't see any output. More oddly still, `UIImagePickerControllerDidCancel` still gets called when the user presses the Cancel button.

Prior suggestions on SO do not seem helpful as I have set the delegate and set the editing properties accordingly unlike in these popular posts:

[uiimagepickercontroller didfinishpickingmediawithinfo NOT CALLED when selecting a video from the library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27698188/uiimagepickercontroller-didfinishpickingmediawithinfo-not-called-when-selecting)

[UIImagePickerController didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495729/uiimagepickercontroller-didfinishpickingmediawithinfo-not-being-called)

Here's the code to launch the UIImagePickerController (taken from a Ray Wenderlich tutorial):

```
-(BOOL)startCameraControllerFromViewController:(UIViewController*)controller
                                 usingDelegate:(id )delegate {

    if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO)
        || (delegate == nil)
        || (controller == nil)) {
        return NO;
    }

     if(![delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UIImagePickerControllerDelegate) ]) {        
        NSAssert(nil, @"delegate muste conforms to UIImagePickerControllerDelegate protocol");
    }else{
         NSLog(@"delegate does conform to protocol");
     }  

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
    CameraOverlay *overlay = [[CameraOverlay alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)];
    UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    cameraUI.delegate = delegate;
    cameraUI.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];
    cameraUI.allowsEditing = NO;
    //if I comment out the line below, everything works fine.
    //but if I don't comment this out, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo is never called
    cameraUI.cameraOverlayView = overlay;
    [controller presentModalViewController: cameraUI animated: YES];
    return YES;
}
```

Here's the part of `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`:

```
(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    NSLog(@"did finish picking media with info");

    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    // I also tried [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    //despite it not being its own delegate, but in any case
    //this did not change the result

...
}
```

I added the valid delegate check following Andrey's advice, but now I always see "delegate does conform to protocol" regardless of whether the overlay is in and `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` is called.

Any suggestions for what to try or errors in the code? Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what finally worked: set `userInteractionEnabled` to `FALSE` for the overlay view.

I wish I knew whether this was a bug or a feature. I looked at a few tutorials for creating overlay views, and none mentioned setting this property. If anyone can fully explain why this made the difference, I'd like to mark a more complete answer than this.

Answer (score 0):

@sunny finally correct solution! userInteractionEnabled = FALSE did call didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo